# Simple console application that changes text color based on user input

Tags: c#, beginner, console

I am learning C# like 1 or 2 months and I wanted to know if there is any possibility to shorten this code.

It is simple. It only changes color of the console text with `while` loop if you enter wrong input. When you enter it correctly it changes the color + asks you if you want to continue.

It looks weird for me when I have for each color duplicity of the code written before (in if and switch statements) But I have no idea if there is any way to make it cleaner and shorter, but I guess there is. Also I would like to know where is worth to use arrays and where normal strings and integers + if there is any reasonable difference. Also I find it very hard for orientation when I have a lot of strings or ints inside array, but easy to maintain. Thanks for answers

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string[] Arrays = new string[3]{
        "Hello!", "Enter a color\n1 = blue\n2 = red\n3 = Magenta", "Render numbers"

    Console.WriteLine(Arrays[0]);

    bool Continue = true;
    while(Continue) {
        Console.WriteLine(Arrays[1]);

        string[] color = new string[4]{
            "Blue", "Red", "Magenta", "Render numbers : "
        };
        char EnterColor = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
        Console.WriteLine();
        switch (EnterColor) {
            case '1':
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Blue;

                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? y/n");
                string NextTask = Console.ReadLine();
                if (NextTask == "y") {
                    // set loop to repeat
                    Continue = true;
                }
                else {
                    Continue = false;

                }
                break;
            case '2':
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
                Continue = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? y/n");
                string NextTaskRed = Console.ReadLine();
                if (NextTaskRed == "y") {
                    Continue = true;
                }
                else {
                    Continue = false;

                }
                break;
            case '3':
                Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Magenta;
                Continue = false;
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? y/n");
                string NextTasMagenta = Console.ReadLine();
                if (NextTasMagenta == "y") {
                    // set loop to repeat
                    Continue = true;
                }
                else {
                    Continue = false;

                }
                break;
            // there will be render nums option in next case using for loop
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please paste all code, not just the middle of a method.

Comment: Alright i pasted whole code except usings.

Comment: We also need to know what your application is doing. Please discribe its purpose and how it works etc.

Comment: It is simple it only changes color of the console text with while loop if you enter wrong input. When you enter it correctly it changes the color + asks you if you want to continue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Review

**Whitespace**
Use whitespace between the method name and opening parenthesis: `Main (string[] args)` instead of `Main(string[] args)`. The same convention applies to statements such as *while*: `while (Continue)` instead of `while(Continue)`. And also to curly braces: `new string[4] {` instead of `new string[4]{`.

---

**New Line**
Prefer using the new line of the system over a fixed format: use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `\n`.

---

**Comments**
Avoid useless comments such as `//strings`. We all know these are string instances: `"Hello!", "Enter a color\n1 = blue\n2 = red\n3 = Magenta", "Render numbers"`. Don't comment out code that you don't use, remove it entirely: `//string Nums = "";`.

---

**Naming conventions**
Use pascalCase for variable names: `string[] arrays` instead of `string[] Arrays`. But what does *arrays* mean? Use a meaningful instead: `string[] promptMessages` for instance.

---

**Using an array or not**
There is no reason to wrap the messages in an array. `Console.WriteLine(Arrays[1]);` is a disaster for readability. `Console.WriteLine("Enter a color ..");` is much cleaner. On the other hand, `string[] color` could have been declared as `ConsoleColor[] colors`. This way, you could have avoided all that repetitive code. You should try to write DRY code.

```
var colors = new ConsoleColor[] {
    ConsoleColor.Blue, 
    ConsoleColor.Red, 
    ConsoleColor.Magenta
};

// NOTE: this is a trivial parsing, you should perform some validation..
// 0 for Blue, 1 for Red, 2 for Magenta
char userColor = int.Parse(Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString());

Console.ForegroundColor = colors[userColor];
Console.WriteLine("Do you want to continue? y/n");
var nextTask = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;
Continue = nextTask == 'y';
```

---

**Console input**
Don't read an entire line when you only need a single character: `string NextTask = Console.ReadLine(); if (NextTask == "y") { ..`. You can read a single character: `string NextTask = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar;`. Unlike `ReadLine`, `ReadKey` does not wait for *Enter* key to be pressed, but immediately returns the pressed key.

Comment: You should add that `Console.ReadKey()` doesn't wait for the user to press enter. It returns on any key press.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! Yes it makes sense to me. The main method was generated by visual studio tho. But i still didn't get where is worth to use string arrays.

Comment: @Xiaoy312 Good point, added.

Comment: You understand the part about _ConsoleColor[] colors_ to avoid redundant code? Was I clear enough?

Comment: Nah that is another thing i don't understand to.

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Oh thanks a lot this is exactly what I was  looking for.